# Parsing error! Can't parse Can't parse the stringorg.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, php, android, json

I'm currently working on android project related with database connectivity. As a part of App, there is an activity that form to insert data into database and retrieve the response whether it is inserted or not. Activity inserts data into database properly But, It fires an JSON parsing exception an couldn't get the response.
Here is my logcat scrreen:

```
03-31 09:49:38.196: D/JSON String:(884): Connection Error
03-31 09:49:38.236: D/Parsing Error!(884): Can't parse the stringorg.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
03-31 09:49:38.236: D/Exception!(884): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-31 09:49:38.526: W/InputMethodManagerService(373): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@b410d300 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@b40b3160
```

Here is my PHP Database connection script:config.inc.php
I think it is faulty!!

```
<?php

    $username = "homeyadmin";
    $password = "8YvUPxCsVHEca2Ru";
    $host = "localhost";
    $dbname = "homey_db";

    //Communicate via UTF8
    $options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8');

    try {
        //Is this required??
        // $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options);
        mysql_connect('localhost','$username','$password') or die("Connection Error");
        mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("no db found");

    } catch(PDOException $ex) {
        die("Failed to connect to Database!" +$ex.toString());
    }

    /*header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    session_start();*/
?>
```

And finally JSONParser class:

```
        public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method, List<NameValuePair> params) {

            try {

                if (method == "POST") {

                    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                    is = httpEntity.getContent();
                    Log.d("Input Stream:", is.toString());

                } else if (method == "GET") {

                    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf8");
                    url += "?" +paramString;
                    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                    is = httpEntity.getContent();

                } 
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.toString();
            }

            try {

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"),8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                json = sb.toString();
                Log.d("JSON String:", json);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Buffer Error!", "Can't convert result" +e.toString());
            }

            //Time to parse the string into JSONObject

            try {
                jobj = new JSONObject(json);
            } catch (JSONException ex) {
                Log.d("Parsing Error!", "Can't parse the string" +ex.toString());
            }

            return jobj;        
        }
}
```

Here is my php code

```
<?php

require("config.inc.php"); 

    if(!empty($_POST)){

        if (empty($_POST['FNAME']) || empty($_POST['LNAME']) || empty($_POST['EMAIL']) || empty($_POST['PASS'])
        || empty($_POST['HNAME']) || empty($_POST['HPNO']) || empty($_POST['HADD2']) 
        || empty($_POST['HLANDMARK']) || empty($_POST['HNAME'])
        || empty($_POST['HCOUNTRY']) || empty($_POST['HSTATE']) 
        || empty($_POST['HCITY']) || empty($_POST['HPHONE'])) {

            //Creating JSON response
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "All the fields are required!";

            die(json_encode($response));
        }
        //List OF variables
        $fname = $_POST['FNAME'];
        $lname = $_POST['LNAME'];
        $email = $_POST['EMAIL'];
        $pass = $_POST['PASS'];
        $hname = $_POST["HNAME"];
        $hpno = $_POST["HPNO"];
        $hadd2 = $_POST["HADD2"];
        $hland = $_POST["HLANDMARK"];
        $hcon = $_POST["HCOUNTRY"];
        $hstate = $_POST["HSTATE"];
        $hcity = $_POST["HCITY"];
        $hphone = $_POST["HPHONE"];     

        //If page not died
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT 1 FROM owner_info WHERE owner_email = '$email'");
        $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
        echo $num;
        $i = 0;
        if($num = $i) {
            //JSON Response
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "Email ID is already in use!";

            die(json_encode($response));
        }
        //If None of these condition followed
        $query = "INSERT INTO
            owner_info (owner_fname, owner_lname, owner_email, owner_pass)
            VALUES('$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$pass')
        ";

        if(mysql_query($query)){
            echo "done";
        }else{
            echo mysql_error();
        }

        $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT owner_id
            FROM owner_info
            WHERE owner_email = '$email'
        ");
        if ($result1) {
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
                echo $temp_owner_id = $row['owner_id'];
            }
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO
                hostel_info (h_owner_id, h_name, h_plot_no, h_address2, h_landmark, h_country, h_state, h_city, h_contact_no)
                VALUES ('$temp_owner_id', '$hname', '$hpno', '$hadd2', '$hland', '$hcon', '$hstate', '$hcity', '$hphone')
            ");
            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["message"] = "Data inserted successfully.";
            die(json_encode($response));
        } else {
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "Database Error!!";
            die(json_encode($response));    
        }

    }
```

Please Help guys!!

Comment: Even if it is on localhost, it's best practice not to post real passwords.

Comment: give the php file where you have echoed the response array which will be parsed by Android

Comment: You fail to check for the HTTP return code here. It looks like it is not 200, and the PHP page throws an error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting invalid JSON, that's why it is not parsed.
Just add this code to see what you get from server:

```
    try {
            jobj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException ex) {
            Log.d("Parsing Error!", "Can't parse the string" +ex.toString());
            Log.d("STRING_FROM_SERVER", json);
        }
```

Comment: Figured it out Guys!!
There is fault in my php code.
I echoed some sentences.
that's why i'm getting invalid JSON.
Thanks for support guys!!